# Integer programming : how to express that one linear constraint implies another?

Tags: integer-programming, constraints

I have formulated a linearly-constrained integer optimization problem. For now, I have been solving it by using an exhaustive search approach over the integer variables. However, I would now like to increase the number of variables, and of course, the size of the search space increases very quickly. Thus, I would like to formulate my problem as a mixed-integer program.

I would like to express many constraints of the following form:
$$ i \leq j \implies a x + b \leq 0$$
Where the variables are $(i, j) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are constant parameters.

I notably *do not* want:
$$a x + b \leq 0 \implies i \leq j $$

Thus any constraint that enforces equivalence between the left and right side of the implication is off the table.

So far I have looked into the Gurobi [general constraints](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/constraints.html) but they only support having a binary variable activating a constraint i.e. something like:
$$ k = 1 \implies { i \leq j \wedge a x + b \leq 0 }$$
With $k \in \{0, 1\}$.

In my admittedly limited testing, this did *not* yield the same results as the original brute-force approach.

Is there a better way to express dependency between constraints ?

Comment: My bad, the produce for "If-Then" constraints is outlined on this page:
http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the procedure for "If-Then" constraints is outlined on this page: yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html